# Query to Return Records with Consecutive Dates by Group in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a date and an ID field. An extract is set out below. I would like to run a query to return all records where the same ID appears on consecutive dates. There may be no consecutive dates or two or more consecutive dates.

Here is the extract:

| Date | No_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 09/06/2021 | 24694000 |
| 09/06/2021 | 20102886 |
| 09/06/2021 | 12873514 |
| 09/06/2021 | 21307300 |
| 09/06/2021 | 13310606 |
| 10/06/2021 | 24694000 |
| 10/06/2021 | 14590427 |
| 10/06/2021 | 23520905 |
| 10/06/2021 | 7424945 |
| 10/06/2021 | 11437404 |
| 10/06/2021 | 12873514 |

Desired output:

| Date | No_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 09/06/2021 | 24694000 |
| 09/06/2021 | 12873514 |
| 10/06/2021 | 24694000 |
| 10/06/2021 | 12873514 |

Comment: You show two pairs of duplicate records. I can get a result that returns distinct records - 2 records from the example. Will that work for your needs?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean June

Comment: Your output shows 4 records which are duplicate pairs. My output will return 2 unique records.

Comment: They aren't duplicates as they have different dates?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I need to get to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Table1.Date, Table1.No_ID
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT [Date], [Date]-1 AS PrevDate, No_ID FROM Table1)  AS Dup ON (Table1.No_ID = Dup.No_ID) AND (Table1.Date = Dup.[PrevDate])
UNION SELECT Table1.Date, Table1.No_ID
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT [Date], [Date]+1 AS NextDate, No_ID FROM Table1)  AS Dup ON (Table1.No_ID = Dup.No_ID) AND (Table1.Date = Dup.[NextDate]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1 
where exists (select 1
              from table1 as tt1
              where tt1.no_id = t1.no_id and
                    tt1.date in (t1.date - 1, t1.date + 1)
             );
```

This is pretty much a direct translation of the question you are asking.